Is there a compact formula for the number of natural solutions of a linear inequality with real coefficients?
I have an inequality in integer nonnegative x,y
x+a*y<=c

where a,c - real positive.
The number of solutions equals
sum (int(c-i*a)+1 for i in range(int(c/a)+1)

Is there a compact (O(1)) formula for this number?

((c-ia)+1)((c/a)+1)/2 ?

I does not work in general case. Unfortunately
